# Exctract specific data with self-check

Tags: mysql

I have this kind of table with data:

```
+-------------+------------+------------+  
| Name        | Test1      | Test2      |
+-------------+------------+------------+  
| A           | 1          |   1        |
+-------------+------------+------------+
| A           | 1          |   1        |
+-------------+------------+------------+    
| A           | 0          |   2        |
+-------------+------------+------------+
| B           | 1          |   1        |
+-------------+------------+------------+
| B           | 2          |   1        |
+-------------+------------+------------+    
| C           | 1          |   1        |
+-------------+------------+------------+
| C           | 1          |   1        |
+-------------+------------+------------+
```

I need to get all names that have all in field test1 and test2 values 1.

In this case output should be like:

```
+-------------+------------+    
| C           | PASS       |
+-------------+------------+
```

Because all records whose name is C and have Test1=1 and Test2=1 are passed,
For example record A cannot pass because one of row have Test1=0 and Test=2.
Same is for B. B have only one record with Test1=1 and Test2=1 but the next record for B have Test1=2 and Test2=1.

How to make query that can extract those data? Or this is better to solve through code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine both `Test1` and `Test2` columns with `UNION`.
Then select the `name` which having both minimum and maximum test value as 1.

**Query**

```
select name,'PASS' as `status`
from
(
    select name,test1 as test
    from tests
    union all
    select name,test2 as test
    from tests
)t
group by name 
having max(t.test) = 1
and min(t.test) = 1;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b2e00/1)

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly that i needed.

Answer (score 1):

My idea is to first choose names that do not fill your rule and then select all remaining ones. Is this your logic?

```
select distinct name, 'PASS' from table
where name not in
(select name from table where test1 <> 1 or test2 <> 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, "PASS" FROM yourtable WHERE test1 = 1 AND test2=1
```

Comment: This query will retrieve A, B and C.